# Why is there no ST_GeographyFromWKB() function?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm developing a [GIS library for PHP](https://github.com/brick/geo), that delegates GIS calculations to the database.

I'm currently using the `ST_GeomFromText()` and `ST_GeomFromWKB()` functions to convert PHP objects to database objects.

I'd now like to add support for PostGIS [Geographies](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/geography.html), so I thought I'd use [ST_GeographyFromText()](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeographyFromText.html) and `ST_GeographyFromWKB()`, but to my surprise, the latter does not exist.

**Is there any reason why `ST_GeographyFromWKB()` does not exist?**

As far as I understand it, there is no reason why a WKB with the standard format and bounds in `[-180 -90, 180 90]` could not be imported as a Geography.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function exists and is called [`ST_GeogFromWKB`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeogFromWKB.html):

```
SELECT 
  ST_AsText(
ST_GeogFromWKB('\x0101000020e6100000000000000000f03f0000000000000040'));

st_astext  
------------
 POINT(1 2)
(1 Zeile)
```

Comment: Not sure how I missed this. Thanks!